# Unable to install pip install ibm-db

Tags: python, db2, package

I'm trying to install ibm-db package but i'm getting the following error.

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:clidriver\lib "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\
vishal.sivala\OneDrive - David Jones\Desktop\Testing\venv\libs" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\vishal.sivala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\vishal.sivala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Us
ers\vishal.sivala\OneDrive - David Jones\Desktop\Testing\venv\PCbuild\win32" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\N
ETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" db2cli64.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_ibm_db build\temp.win32-3.8\Re
lease\ibm_db.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\ibm_db.cp38-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ibm_db.cp38-win32.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'db2cli64.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Users\vishal.sivala\OneDrive - David Jones\Desktop\Testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\vishal.sivala\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2qkgnojm\\ibm-db\\setup.py';f=
getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\vishal.sivala\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wv9aeo8c\install-record.txt --singl
e-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\vishal.sivala\OneDrive - David Jones\Desktop\Testing\venv\include\site\python3.8\ibm-db"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vishal.sivala\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2qkgnojm\ibm-db\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from 16th June 2020, the ibm_db version 3.0.2 includes support for Python 3.8 on the Microsoft Windows platform.

At April 2020 the python ibm_db module (versions up to v3.0.1) on Microsoft-Windows did not operate with Python 3.8.  Now fixed with ibm_db version 3.0.2 since 16/June/2020.